# Selenium scraper - loop logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am still fighting with scraping this website http://bombayhighcourt.nic.in/party_query.php.

I would like to scrape it for years selected by the user using all possible combinations of dropdown values.

So this are the important pieces of my code:

```
class Scraper(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.mydriver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.mydriver.get(self.url)

    def chooseDropdownOption(self, xpath, option):
        dropdown = self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        Select(dropdown).select_by_value(option)

    def getDropdownOptions(self, xpath):
        dropdown = self.mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        return UI.Select(dropdown).options

(...)

#now I extract all options from each dropdown:
bench_options =  s.getDropdownOptions("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select")
jurisd_options = s.getDropdownOptions("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/select")
petition_options = s.getDropdownOptions("/html/body/form/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select")

#and now I am looping through each list:

 for bench_option in bench_options:
    #LOOP 1
    current_bench_option = bench_option.get_attribute('value')

    for jurisd_option in jurisd_options:
        #LOOP 2
        current_jurisd_option = jurisd_option.get_attribute("value")

        for petition_option in petition_options:
            #LOOP 3
            current_petition_option = petition_option.get_attribute("value")

            for year in range(year_start, year_final+1):
                #LOOP 4

                s.chooseDropdownOption("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select", current_bench_option)                
                s.chooseDropdownOption("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/select", current_jurisd_option)
                s.inputText("/html/body/form/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/input[2]", name)

                s.chooseDropdownOption("/html/body/form/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select", current_petition_option)                


                s.chooseDropdownOption("/html/body/form/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[4]/select", str(year))
                s.clickButton("/html/body/form/table[5]/tbody/tr[1]/td/input[1]")

                #DO SCRAPING PART
                #GO BACK to THE SEARCH PAGE
```

I don't know if there is a cleaner way of doing this kind of tasks but that's not my problem here. My understanding of this procedure is the following:

1. LOOP 1 - Choose first option from the list (Bombay)
2. LOOP 2 - Choose first option from the list (Civil)
3. LOOP 3 - Choose first option from the list (Petitioner)
4. LOOP 4 - Repeat it for each of the years in range
   When the range of years is exhausted I thought the next points would be:
5. LOOP 3 - Choose the second option from the list (Respondend)
6. LOOP 4 - Repeat it again for all years

But after the years range is exhausted it correctly goes back to the search page but I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StaleElementReferenceException            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-09f2da0eea05> in <module>()
     27 
     28         for petition_option in petition_options:
---> 29             current_petition_option = petition_option.get_attribute("value")
     30             print(current_petition_option)
         31 
(...)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=55.0.2883.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.26.436362 (5476ec6bf7ccbada1734a0cdec7d570bb042aa30),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Something is failing in my understanding but I can't find what...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but very often posting a question to SO has an amazing effect on my brain and I find the solution immediately after :) When I get options from the dropdown I should convert them to values immediately. And that's it.

```
bench_options =  s.getDropdownOptions("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select")
bench_options = [x.get_attribute("value") for x in bench_options]
jurisd_options = s.getDropdownOptions("/html/body/form/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[4]/select")
jurisd_options = [x.get_attribute("value") for x in jurisd_options]
petition_options = s.getDropdownOptions("/html/body/form/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/select")
petition_options = [x.get_attribute("value") for x in petition_options]
```

As Andersson points out below, every time I select a value from "Bench" or "Jurisdiction" I make new HTTP requests to server, so I get new page. This means that web-elements defined before selection becomes unattached to DOM and so I cannot handle them anymore, but need to redefine them.

Comment: You should note that when you select a value from `"Bench"` or `"Jurisdiction"` you make new `HTTP` requests to server, so you get new page. This means that web-elements defined before selection becomes unattached to `DOM` and so you cannot handle them anymore, but need to redefine them. Hope this helps you to understand the cause of issue :)